# Linq query ("not in ") on datatable

Tags: linq

I would like to return all rows from `TableA` table that does not exists in another table.

e.g.

```
select bench_id from TableA where bench_id not in (select bench_id from TableB )
```

can you please help me write equivalent LINQ query. Here `TableA` is from Excel and `TableB` is from a Database

I am loading Excel sheet data into `DataTable`, `TableA`. `TableB` I am loading from Database. In short, `TableA` and `TableB` is type of `DataTable`

Comment: In little addition.  I am loading Excel sheet data into DataTable : TableA  and  TableB I am loading from Database. In short, TableA and TableB is type of DataTable.

Answer (score 4):

So if table A is from Excel, are you loading the data into memory first? If so (i.e. you're using LINQ to Objects) then I suggest you load the IDs in table B into a set and then use:

```
var query = tableA.Where(entry => !tableBIdSet.Contains(entry.Id));
```

If this isn't appropriate, please give more details.

Converting into a set is probably best done just by using [the HashSet constructor which takes an `IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301504.aspx). For example:

```
var tableBIdSet = new HashSet<string>(db.TableB.Select(entry => entry.Id));
```

(If the IDs aren't actually distinct, you could add a call to Distinct() at the end.)

Answer (score 1):

```
var lPenaltyEmployee = from row1 in tBal.getPenaltyEmployeeList().AsEnumerable()
                                   select row1;

var PenaltyEmp = new HashSet<string>(lPenaltyEmployee.Select(Entry => Entry.Emsrno);

DataTable lAbsentEmp = (from row in tBal.getAbsentEmployee(txtFromDate.Text).AsEnumerable()
                                    where !(PenaltyEmp).Contains(row["Emsrno"].ToString())
                                    select row).CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
From a in TableA
Group Join b in TableB on a.bench_id Equalsb.bench_id into g = Group
Where g.Count = 0
Select a
```